# Allow dashes on a field using jQuery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, regex

I tried to add a rule for a specific field that only accepts letters, numbers, dashes and underscores but dashes is not included into the rule. Question is, how can I add the dashes to the characters using the below format.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("custom-rule", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\w+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Letters, numbers, dashes and underscores only please");
```

Comment: `/^[\w-]+$/i.test(value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dashes along with word character in the regex using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html).

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("custom-rule", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[\w-]+$/i.test(value);
    // here add dash in character class-^^^^-----
}, "Letters, numbers, dashes and underscores only please");
```

Comment: Ahaa! so it needs to be inside the brackets. Thanks!